# Saxon - s9api - setParameter as node and access in transformation

Tags: saxon, s9api

we are trying to add parameters to a transformation at the runtime. The only possible way to do so, is to set every single parameter and not a node. We don't know yet how to create a node for the setParameter.

Current setParameter:

`QName TEST XdmAtomicValue 24`

Expected setParameter:

`<TempNode> <local>Value1</local> </TempNode>`

We searched and tried to create a XdmNode and XdmItem.

Comment: Which version, which platform? In recent versions of SaxonJ you should be able to create simple documents with e.g. `SaplingDocument`/`SaplingNode` see https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/sapling/SaplingDocument.html and e.g. https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/sapling/SaplingElement.html

Comment: You would then get an `XdmNode` with https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/sapling/SaplingElement.html#toXdmNode(net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an `XdmNode` by parsing XML, the best way to do it is:

```
DocumentBuilder db = processor.newDocumentBuilder();
XdmNode node = db.build(new StreamSource(
                  new StringReader("<doc><elem/></doc>")));
```

You could also pass a string containing lexical XML as the parameter value, and then convert it to a tree by calling the XPath `parse-xml()` function.

If you want to construct the XdmNode programmatically, there are a number of options:

1. `DocumentBuilder.newBuildingStreamWriter()` gives you an instance of `BuildingStreamWriter` which extends `XmlStreamWriter`, and you can create the document by writing events to it using methods such as `writeStartElement`, `writeCharacters`, `writeEndElement`; at the end call `getDocumentNode()` on the `BuildingStreamWriter`, which gives you an `XdmNode`. This has the advantage that `XmlStreamWriter` is a standard API, though it's not actually a very nice one, because the documentation isn't very good and as a result implementations vary in their behaviour.
2. Another event-based API is Saxon's Push class; this differs from most push-based event APIs in that rather than having a flat sequence of methods like:

```
    builder.startElement('x'); 
    builder.characters('abc'); 
    builder.endElement();
```

you have a nested sequence:

```
    Element x = Document.elem('x');
    x.text('abc');
    x.close();
```

3. As mentioned by Martin, there is the "sapling" API: `Saplings.doc().withChild(elem(...).withChild(elem(...))` etc. This API is rather radically different from anything you might be familiar with (though it's influenced by the LINQ API for tree construction on .NET) but once you've got used to it, it reads very well. The Sapling API constructs a very light-weight tree in memory (hance the name), and converts it to a fully-fledged XDM tree with a final call of `SaplingDocument.toXdmNode()`.
4. If you're familiar with DOM, JDOM2, or XOM, you can construct a tree using any of those libraries and then convert it for use by Saxon. That's a bit convoluted and only really intended for applications that are already using a third-party tree model heavily (or for users who love these APIs and prefer them to anything else).

Answer (score 0):

In the Saxon Java s9api, you can construct temporary trees as SaplingNode/SaplingElement/SaplingDocument, see https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/sapling/SaplingDocument.html and https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/sapling/SaplingElement.html.

To give you a simple example constructing from a Map, as you seem to want to do:

```
    Processor processor = new Processor();

    Map<String, String> xsltParameters = new HashMap<>();
    xsltParameters.put("foo", "value 1");
    xsltParameters.put("bar", "value 2");

    SaplingElement saplingElement = new SaplingElement("Test");

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> param : xsltParameters.entrySet())
    {
        saplingElement = saplingElement.withChild(new SaplingElement(param.getKey()).withText(param.getValue()));
    }

    XdmNode paramNode = saplingElement.toXdmNode(processor);

    System.out.println(paramNode);
```

outputs e.g. `<Test><bar>value 2</bar><foo>value 1</foo></Test>`.

So the key is to understand that `withChild()` returns a new `SaplingElement`.

The code can be compacted using streams e.g.

```
    XdmNode paramNode2 = Saplings.elem("root").withChild(
            xsltParameters
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(p -> Saplings.elem(p.getKey()).withText(p.getValue()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    .toArray(SaplingElement[]::new))
            .toXdmNode(processor);

    System.out.println(paramNode2);
```